# How has mathematical terminology changed since 1900?

Tags: math-history

I opened a rather old dictionary dating back to 1904, and it categorised certain terms by a subject-category i.e. [Math] to denote mathematics. I specifically searched out for [Math] as I was most interested to see how the definitions compared to modern definitions of the same term.

I also stumbled upon various mathematical terms, that seemed so simple by definition but I have not ever experienced them in education and neither come across them in articles (maybe I haven't read enough!).

Such terms, as Aliquant and Aliquot.

I understand that new terms are being added as mathematics develops, and definitions are being rewritten with advancements in that subject.

Why is it that these terms that may be in the childs or adults vocabularry as a mathematician, not have much frequent use today?

Comment: This will be better answered in History of Science and Mathematics StackExchange :https://hsm.stackexchange.com/

Comment: "Aliquot" is still in (limited) use in Number Theory.

Comment: It has changed since I was in school, which was somewhat later than 1900. Makes it hard for me to understand some of the questions and answers here, even when they're talking about something I understand.

Comment: "How" ? Impossible to answer.... Language changes.